# Dynamically creating an element and trying to pass its value as a parameter in a function onkeyup

Tags: javascript

I am adding a row to a table.  In one of the cells in the row is an input which I want to make an ajax call.  However, I am having a problem with passing the value of the input.

I've illustrated the problem here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <script language="javascript">
      function addElement(){
        var id = 0;
        var tbl = document.getElementById('myTable');
        var rowInd = document.getElementById('row1').rowIndex;
        rowInd++;
        var row0 = tbl.insertRow( rowInd );
        var cell = row0.insertCell(0);
        // cell.innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="myInput'+id+'" value="hello world" onkeyup="alert( '+this.value+' );" />';
        // acts as expected:  hello world
        // cell.innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="myInput'+id+'" value="hello world" onkeyup="makeAjaxRequest( \'value='+this.value+'\' )" />';
        // Outputs:  value=undefined
        var theId = "myInput"+id;
        // cell.innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="myInput'+id+'" value="hello world" onkeyup="makeAjaxRequest( \'value='+document.getElementById( theId ).value+'\' )" />';
        // Output:  Object required
        cell.innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="myInput'+id+'" value="hello world" onkeyup=" function(){ makeAjaxRequest( \'value='+this.value+'\' ) }" />';
        // Nothing happens
      }

      function makeAjaxRequest( val ){
        alert( val );
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <span onclick="addElement()">
      Click me
    </span>
    <br /><br />
    <table id="myTable">
      <tr id="row1"><td>hello</td></tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

It's going straight to an ajax call, so I need to be able to access either the object or the value so that I do my search.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: where you calling this makeAjaxRequest.. tell me please

Comment: It's in the code above.  It's just an alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for making me discover insertRow, rowIndex and insertCell!

Btw, you're complicating your life for nothing.

```
cell.innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="myInput'+id+'" value="hello world" onkeyup=" function(){ makeAjaxRequest( \'value='+this.value+'\' ) }" />';
```

Here is the correct way (DOM-compatible, without innerHTML evil, blablabla):

```
var input = document.createElement('input')
input.type = 'text'
input.id = 'myInput' + id
input.value = 'hello world'
input.onkeyup = function() {
    makeAjaxRequest(this.value) // this is how to make it work
}
cell.appendChild(input) // or use replaceChild depending on your needs
```

The problem when you pass `'value=' + this.value` is that you're passing the following value: `value=hello world`.

The other problem is that for inline event handlers (like the `onkeyup` in the HTML) is that you don't need to wrap in a function. The following would work:

```
cell.innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="myInput'+id+'" value="hello world" onkeyup="makeAjaxRequest( this.value );" />';
```

I haven't tested, but I suspect that by wrapping in another function, the `this` is different. Thus why it can't work.

To avoid any ambiguity, don't use HTML event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass value like this :-

```
  urlData = "" ;
    postData = "vendorType=" + jQuery('#EnrollmentRoleId').val() + "&time=" + new Date().getTime();

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: urlData,
        data: postData,
        success: function(data) {
            //alert(data);
            jQuery('#EnrollmentVendorId').html(data);
            jQuery('#user_id_div').show();
            jQuery('#loading_image').hide();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, but I'm not using JQuery and I'm not having an AJAX issue. Everything is happening in the same file.

Comment: u tried onchange or something in place of onkeyup.. did u checked it is calling ur function properly..