# Dynamic created control in java script is not passing to next page in java

Tags: javascript

while I am try to get its value on next page after submission, dynamic created control is not accessible. Its working fine in IE

```
<script>
function myfunction(){

var element = document.createElement("input");

   //Assign different attributes to the element.
   element.setAttribute("type", "text");
   element.setAttribute("value", "sdf");
   element.setAttribute("name", "mytxt");
   element.setAttribute("id", "mytxt");

   var myDiv=document.getElementById("mydiv");
   myDiv.appendChild(element);
}
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean on "next page"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10084461/dynamically-creating-an-element-and-trying-to-pass-its-value-as-a-parameter-in-a

Comment: add `window.onload = function ...`

Comment: How is the form submitted?

Comment: Submitted form using POST @ AndrewPolland

Comment: I have submitted form using POST

Comment: @EWit After submission of page , On next Servlet get request parameters